# How can I use the JSON attribute name in my table?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON object list fetched from server and I want to create a table with some basic functionalities like delete/update record. The problem is that I want this table to be created for `Entity1` and for `Entity2` too. Now if the entities which should be managed in this way grows it wouldn't be a great idea to create a new table for each entity (duplicate code)

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th> {entity1.firstColumn} </th>        |   <th> {entity2.firstColumn} </th>
   <th> {entity1.secondColumn} </th>       |   <th> {entity2.secondColumn} </th>
   <th> {entity1.thirdColumn} </th>        |   <th> {entity2.thirdColumn} </th>
  </tr>                                    |   <th> {entity3.fourthColumn} </th>
  ...data
</table>
```

So in order to avoid all this boiler-plate code I've thought that I could use the JSON attribute names to create the table header in a function like this:

```
createHeader(JSONList)
{
  let tableHeader=[];
  if(JSONList.length === 0) return null;
  for(//help here)
  { 
    tableHeader.push(<th> {JSON.ATTRIBUTE.NAME.HERE} </th>);
  }
  return tableHeader;
}
```

But I don't know how to iterate through JSON's attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
createHeader(JSONList)
{
    if(JSONList.length === 0) return null;
    return Object.keys(JSONList).map((item, index) => (
        <th key={'thItem'+index}>
        { item }
        </th>
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take first row as sample and extract keys as header. Here is working sample on sample json data

```js
const entity1 = [
  {name: "Deepak", age: 29, address: "Something1"},
  {name: "Deepak1", age: 39, address: "Something1"},
  {name: "Deepak2", age: 19, address: "Something2"},
]
const entity2 = [
  {name: "Deepak", age: 29, address: "Something1"},
  {name: "Deepak1", age: 39, address: "Something1"},
  {name: "Deepak2", age: 19, address: "Something2"},
]

const createHeader = (list) => {
  if(!list || !list.length) return ''
  const headers = Object.keys(list[0])
  return headers.map( header => `<th>${header}</th>`).join("")
}

console.log(createHeader(entity1))
console.log(createHeader(entity2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with this for loop :

```
for(var attribute in JSONList[0])
{
    console.log(var);
}
```